# Loop variables in Laravel's Blade

Tags: php, laravel, loops, templates, laravel-blade

I do quite a lot of loops in Laravel's Blade templates and sometimes, I have to remember some conditions like $found or $needToSave, something like that.

Here is a small example:

```
<?php $found = false; ?>
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->posts as $post)

        @if ($post->something == "value")
            <?php $found = true; ?>
        @endif

        @if ($loop->parent->last)
            @if ($found)
                I really found something! Do something special!
            @endif
        @endif

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now, is there a better way for the `<?php $found = false|true ?>` part?
To me, this seems unclean and I am searching for a cleaner solution, which plays out with the template engine. I know about `@php` but this seems as ugly to me. Is there anything to assign local vars within the engine?

Cheers

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to know if any user has any post with a specific value? If so, you should consider doing this in the controller and even make a database query from it.

Comment: Hm yeah, that's `{{ $found = false }}`  what I had in mind too, but I thought it will print out something, doesn't it? If not, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: You're correct! Sorry! It just returns the variable, I didn't even check when i tested this theory as I dd()'ed the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the variable later, you can refactor your code to:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
        @if ($loop->parent->last && $post->something === 'value')
            I really found something! Do something special!
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

In case if you'll use it in the future, you can use [`@php`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php) and [`@endphp`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php)

> In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You can use the Blade `@php` directive to execute a block of plain PHP within your template

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#php

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote, I know about @php, yet I was searching for a solution something like @local("found", "something") or so. The $post->something is just an example. I run much more complex conditions and need to keep a marker every now and then.

Comment: @AndreasHerbert there is no such thing in Blade, so it's better to use `@php` or just refactor the code.